# Views sortable table column exposes field name in url

Tags: views

I have created a view that uses a table format with several columns. Via format settings, I have chosen some of them to be sortable (by checking the respective checkboxes and and selecting the default order). While this is working great, I have noticed that when clicking the sortable column in the ui, the respective url parameter "order" uses the actual machine name of the field, thus exposing internal db info (order=field_my_custom_field_name). Is there a way to adjust this so an alias is used instead? I am looking for a similar functionality as in "Filter identifier" for Filter Criteria

Comment: I answered to the same question here: [How to change the field name in the url when using views exposed sort?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/86495/16739)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the field name in the url when using views exposed sort?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86491/how-to-change-the-field-name-in-the-url-when-using-views-exposed-sort)